# How to add ; at the end of each "show create table"

Tags: regex, python-3.x, shell, unix, hive

So, I have a txt file that has the below content in it:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `table1`(
  `tab_id bigint COMMENT 'The unique identifier of thetable')
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  *
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
* 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  *
LOCATION
  *
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1556u3ehw27')
CREATE TABLE `table2`(
  `count` bigint)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
 * 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  *
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  *
LOCATION
  'hdfs://path/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'transient'='15407')
```

**As you can see, after each table's DDL, there is no ; at the end of it.I am trying to write a program that inserts a ; after each one of the tables DDL's. So the output should be like:**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `table1`(
  `tab_id bigint COMMENT 'The unique identifier of thetable')
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  *
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
* 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  *
LOCATION
  *
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1556u3ehw27');
CREATE TABLE `table2`(
      `count` bigint)
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 
     * 
    STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
      *
    OUTPUTFORMAT 
      *
    LOCATION
      'hdfs://path/'
    TBLPROPERTIES (
      'transient'='15407');
```

**There are  two ways I have tried this. (1) By adding it the the DDL creation script and a python program.**

Below is my DDL creation .sh script which runs through my database's tables and generates a single file for all the tables within a database.I tried to use the cat function shown below on the last line(# cat...) to do that but kept receiving errors.

```
 hiveDBName=my_db;

showcreate="show create table "

 showpartitions="show partitions "

 terminate=";"

 tables=`hive -e "use $hiveDBName;show tables;"`

 tab_list=`echo "${tables}"`

 rm -f ${hiveDBName}_all_table_partition_DDL.sql

 for list in $tab_list
 do
        echo "Generating table script for " ${hiveDBName}.${list}
        showcreatetable=${showcreatetable}${showcreate}${hiveDBName}.${list}${terminate}

 done

 echo " ====== Create Tables ======= : " $showcreatetable

##Remove the file
      rm -f ${hiveDBName}_extract_all_tables.txt

      hive -e "use $hiveDBName; ${showcreatetable}" > /home/path/filter_ddls/aa.sql
      grep -v "WARN" /home/path/filter_ddls/aa.sql >/home/path/hive_db_ddls/${hiveDBName}_extract_all_tables.sql
     # cat a1.sql + ";\n\n" >> ${hiveDBName}_extract_all_tables.sql
```

Below is my Python program but the output of this method adds ; only after tblproperties which skips certain tables.

```
import re
f = open("/home/path/ddl.sql", 'rt', encoding='latin-1').read()

with open("/home/path/new_ddl.sql","w") as output:
    output.write(re.sub(r'(TBLPROPERTIES \(.*?\))', r'\1;', f, flags=re.DOTALL))
```

Any ideas or suggestion to make this happen? Preferable the first option (the .sh script).

Comment: If your file format doesn't change and `transient` is always present in the line before the addition is needed, you could simply use `sed` to add them with `sed '/transient/s/$/;/' file`

Comment: I am kind of new to shell scripting. Do you know how to incorporate that inside the code above?

Comment: What is the text file name? You can place this anywhere in the script AFTER the text file has been generated. (and depending on how it is generated, you could even pipe the output of whatever generates the text file through the `sed` command and write the finished product out) And why do you do `tab_list=\`echo "${tables}"` after `tables` is filled? You are just forcing word-splitting to occur?

Comment: the text file name is aa.sql. COuld I chat with you?

Comment: Sure, as soon as one of us sees the "Continue in chat" button (which doesn't always show up), I'm happy to chat with you. What you can do it add `sed '/transient/s/$/;/' aa.sql` which will add the `';'` after the `')'`.

Comment: Perfect, let me see if I can try and do that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197001/discussion-between-david-c-rankin-and-james-davinport).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following our discussion in chat, the two solutions discussed were as follows:

If your format is consistent and `transient` is always present in the line where a closing `';'` is required at the end, then a simple `sed` substitution is all that is needed, e.g.

```
sed '/transient/s/$/;/' file
```

(add the `-i` option to edit the file in-place, and/or add `-i.bak` to edit in place preserving the original file unchanged with the `.bak` extension)

If on the other hand, the content can change and `transient` may or may not be present, then you can key off the `TBLPROPERTIES` tag and then scan forward in the file to find the first closing `')'` following `TBLPROPERTIES` and add the closing `';'` there.

`awk` provides a more robust solution there as no guarantees have been given as to the possible number of lines between `TBLPROPERTIES` and the closing `')'`. Below `awk` is used with a simple variable `look` to server as a flag indicating whether you are *looking* for the closing `')'` after a `TBLPROPERTIES` (`look=1`), or not (`look=0`).

For example:

```
awk -v look=0 '
    /^TBLPROPERTIES/ { look=1 }
    look == 1 {
        if ( sub (/[)]$/,");") )
            look=0
    }1
' file
```

GNU `awk` has `gawk -i inplace` extension to allow editing the file in-place, similar to `sed`, otherwise you simply redirect the output to a temp file and then copy or move to the original filename.

Whether using `sed` or `awk` above, the output has the desired terminating `';'`, e.g.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `table1`(
  `tab_id bigint COMMENT 'The unique identifier of thetable')
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  *
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
*
OUTPUTFORMAT
  *
LOCATION
  *
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1556u3ehw27');
CREATE TABLE `table2`(
  `count` bigint)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
 *
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  *
OUTPUTFORMAT
  *
LOCATION
  'hdfs://path/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'transient'='15407');
```

Let me know if you have further questions.