# How to add a ; at the end of a hive ddl extract

Tags: python, shell, unix, hive

I am am trying to generate the ddls(show create tables) for my hive tables but when I run my shell script, there is no ; at the end of each table.

Here is my code:

```
 hiveDBName=dal_std;
 showcreate="show create table "
 showpartitions="show partitions "
 terminate=";"
 tables=`hive -e "use $hiveDBName;show tables;"`
 tab_list=`echo "${tables}"`

 rm -f ${hiveDBName}_all_table_partition_DDL.txt

  for list in $tab_list
  do
         echo "Generating table script for " ${hiveDBName}.${list}
          showcreatetable=${showcreatetable}${showcreate}${hiveDBName}.${list}${terminate}

        done

        echo " ====== Create Tables ======= : " $showcreatetable

        ## Remove the file
        rm -f ${hiveDBName}_extract_all_tables.txt

        hive -e "use $hiveDBName; ${showcreatetable}"> a.sql
      grep -v "WARN" a.sql > a1.sql
       # cat a1.sql + ";\n\n" >> ${hiveDBName}_extract_all_tables.txt
```

This runs and outputs a file with all of its ddl properties but there is no ; after each "create external or create table ddls.

Any sugestions on how to add a ; after each table?

Comment: Can you show example (in- and) output? I don't know the typical output of hive, so something like `sed 's/$/;/'` or `sed 's/^$/;/'` would be random tries.

Comment: Why this question and also https://stackoverflow.com/q/57204923/3220113 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add ; at the end of each "show create table"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57204923/how-to-add-at-the-end-of-each-show-create-table)